# AngularJS referencing parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement the following behavior. I am including a template using ng-inculde where I am doing something like this: {{something}}

I want that **'something'** to have double binding with another variable in the parent controller's scope and to have the ability to set the name of property of the parent controller's scope. So on one include, something will reference an apple and on other include, something will reference an orange.

What I do is, that I wrote a custom controller which has a `lookAt(v)` method and i am calling this method in ng-init of the div where i use ng-include and ng-controller. In this method, I am trying to set the binding but it does not work. I assume, that parent scope already has that variable defined.

Here is my code:

```
mod.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.lookAt = function (variable) {
        $scope.something=$scope[variable];
    }
}]);
```

Thanks for any suggestion on how to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? If i understand you correctly, you want to implement an Observer pattern. In AngularJS you can use $watch for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your template that is pulled in with ng-include, instead of `{{something}}` use `something()`, where the `something` method is defined on the parent controller.

You can still init your variable name if you want:

```
mod.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.initMethod = function(variable) {
       $scope.variable = variable;
    }
    $scope.something = function () {
        return $scope[$scope.variable];
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Controller As Syntax you can't just do `$scope.$parent` in the consumer (constructor for child) you need to address the parent's data-object like so: `$scope.$parent.vmParent`.